# JavaFX set action to button in another class

Tags: javafx

I created listview in my application and its item has a delete button:

```
    public Cell() {
    super();
    this.delete = new Button("delete");

    // I have also image and other labels in this cell
    this.hBox.getChildren().addAll(productImage, amountLabel, priceLabel, delete);
    HBox.setHgrow(pane, Priority.ALWAYS);
    delete.setOnAction(event -> getListView().getItems().remove(getItem()));
}
```

But in my main controller window when I click this button amount field and amountLabel must be changed which are my main controller class:

```
@FXML
void addToShopCart(ActionEvent event) {
    selectedPart.setAmount(amount);
    selectedPart.setSumma(amount*selectedPart.getPrice());
    shopListView.getItems().add(selectedPart);

    summa += amount*selectedPart.getPrice();
    totalPriceLabel.setText(summa + "$");
} // this is when I add an item to the list
```

Now I don't know how to subtract amount from summa that was added. For this I tried return button like this:

```
Cell cell;
@FXML
void initialize() {
    cell = new Cell();
    shopListView.setCellFactory(param -> cell));
    Button button = cell.getDeleteButton();
    button.setOnAction(...//some action)
}
```

But it doesn't help. I tried to cut the code.

Comment: You need to register a listener with the list view’s `items` list, and recompute the total when the list changes. (Forget about the button, just think about the *data*.)

Comment: @James_D, yes I did as you said. I just removed the button in list view and added to the main window. Thank you